# create a file with prefix =file1 followed by the random number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel, touch

Using RANDOM function and touch command ,  create a file with prefix =file1 followed by the random number.

when you run the script it should created a file with a random number.before creating, make sure the file doesn't exist using -f option.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are **expected to show** at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You want to test the existence with -f and then create a file. But what happens, if between test and creation another task creates the file? `mktemp` can resolve this problem:

```
filename=$( mktemp ./file1-XXXXXXXXXX ) || exit 1
```

In this case, an empty file is created (like using `touch`). The `XXXXXXXXXX` part is replaced by a random alphanumeric string. The file anme is stored into `filename`. On error `exit 1` is executed.